# Как поменять отображение даты?

Tags: python, datetime

Всем привет! У меня есть переменная, в которой лежит дата  ['26 сентября 2020']
Как с помощью datetime поменять формат на ['26/09/2020'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала задайте локаль (достаточно один раз в начале программы). Если у вас система уже настроена на русский язык, то достаточно выполнить следующие команды:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

Если язык системы другой, то вместо пустых кавычек укажите требуемую локаль.

```
do = datetime.datetime.strptime("26 сентябрь 2020", "%d %B %Y")
do.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Обратите внимание как у вас должен быть записан месяц - `сентябрь`